# Starting node application with `node` works but not when starting it with `/usr/bin/node`

Tags: javascript, node.js, service

I am trying to set up node application as a `service` and to start the service I need to start node with an absolute path, which means I have to start it with `usr/bin/node`, however for whatever reason my application doesn't work correctly when using this absolute path.

## Does work

```
root@server:/etc/systemd/system# node /var/www/gwart./mediawiki/extensions/VisualEditor/parsoid/bin/server.js
{"name":"parsoid","hostname":"server.live-servers.net","pid":25057,"level":30,"levelPath":"info/service-runner","msg":"master(25057) initializing 2 workers","time":"2018-12-15T21:47:27.192Z","v":0}
{"name":"lib/index.js","hostname":"server.live-servers.net","pid":25068,"level":30,"levelPath":"info","msg":"loading ...","time":"2018-12-15T21:47:28.749Z","v":0}
{"name":"lib/index.js","hostname":"server.live-servers.net","pid":25068,"level":30,"levelPath":"info","msg":"ready on :8000","time":"2018-12-15T21:47:28.781Z","v":0}
{"name":"lib/index.js","hostname":"server.live-servers.net","pid":25082,"level":30,"levelPath":"info","msg":"loading ...","time":"2018-12-15T21:47:30.325Z","v":0}
{"name":"lib/index.js","hostname":"server.live-servers.net","pid":25082,"level":30,"levelPath":"info","msg":"ready on :8000","time":"2018-12-15T21:47:30.351Z","v":0}
{"name":"parsoid","hostname":"server.live-servers.net","pid":25057,"level":40,"levelPath":"warn/service-runner","msg":"startup finished","time":"2018-12-15T21:47:30.353Z","v":0}
{"name":"parsoid","hostname":"server.live-servers.net","pid":25082,"level":30,"logType":"info","wiki":"wiki$0","title":"Main_Page","oldId":null,"reqId":null,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36","msg":"started wt2html","longMsg":"started wt2html","levelPath":"info","time":"2018-12-15T21:47:39.266Z","v":0}
{"name":"parsoid","hostname":"server.live-servers.net","pid":25082,"level":30,"logType":"info","wiki":"wiki$0","title":"Main_Page","oldId":5,"reqId":null,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36","msg":"completed wt2html in 1144.7718710899353ms","longMsg":"completed wt2html in 1144.7718710899353ms","levelPath":"info","time":"2018-12-15T21:47:40.391Z","v":0}
^Z
[23]+  Stopped
```

## Does not work

```
root@server:/etc/systemd/system# /usr/bin/node /var/www/gwart/mediawiki/extensions/VisualEditor/parsoid/bin/server.js
    {"name":"parsoid","hostname":"server.live-servers.net","pid":25145,"level":30,"levelPath":"info/service-runner","msg":"master(25145) initializing 2 workers","time":"2018-12-15T21:47:49.939Z","v":0}
    {"name":"parsoid","hostname":"server.live-servers.net","pid":25155,"level":60,"moduleName":"lib/index.js","levelPath":"fatal/service-runner/worker","msg":"Unexpected token ...","time":"2018-12-15T21:47:50.657Z","v":0}
    {"name":"parsoid","hostname":"server.live-servers.net","pid":25145,"level":40,"message":"first worker died during startup, continue startup","worker_pid":25155,"exit_code":1,"startup_attempt":1,"levelPath":"warn/service-runner/master","msg":"first worker died during startup, continue startup","time":"2018-12-15T21:47:51.668Z","v":0}
```

Comment: what does `which node` output?

Comment: `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin/node`

Comment: check the version of `/usr/bin/node` - you probably have a never version and need to downgrade

Comment: alternatively, try starting with `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin/node` as the absolute path

Comment: Interesting indeed. I use NVM but ye, let me try that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have different versions of node installed on different paths and your application might require a particular version to run correctly. Consider adding `console.log(process.version);` to the start of your script, run it with both commands, and  compare the output. If they are different versions, you might need to add a symlink to the correct version in your nvm folder in `/usr/bin/node`.

Comment: Nailed it mate! I didn't know :)